# ORACLE SQL - Relatório complexo

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom dia,
Preciso tirar um relatório que não é disponibilizado pelo sistema, trabalhando com a tabela faturas. Nessa tabela existe os dados do cliente, unidade consumidora e o valor do débito. Acontece que um cliente pode ter mais de uma unidade consumidora e, em cada unidade consumidora, preciso o total do débito. Exemplo:

```
cliente a | Unidade consumidora 1 | Total de débitos

          | Unidade consumidora 2 | Total de débitos

cliente b | Unidade consumidora 3 | Total de débitos

cliente c | Unidade consumidora 4 | Total de débitos

          | Unidade consumidora 5 | Total de débitos

          | Unidade consumidora 6 | Total de débitos
```

Estou enfrentando problemas com o GROUP BY porque, por causa da função soma, tenho que agrupar o cliente e unidade consumidora, e o relatório gerado acaba saindo de maneira errada. Como eu posso solucionar?

Tentei utilizar:

```
SELECT cliente, unidade_consumidora, sum(valor_fatura) "Total de débitos"

from cad_fatura

GROUP BY cliente, unidade_consumidora

ORDER BY cliente, unidade consumidora
```

Comment: coloque um exemplo dos dados retornados, e um exemplo dos dados que precisa. (até serve o que já está na pergunta, mas o nome dos clientes irão se repetir nas linhas inferiores)

Comment: Sendo Oracle pensaria em "analytic functions" https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/a-window-into-the-world-of-analytic-functions

Comment: Não teria problema os dados do cliente repetir, mas está retornando os dados de clientes com apenas uma unidade consumidora. Vou dar uma olhada nas analytic functions, obrigado.